# Convert for loop to JSTL/EL expression

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el

I have this loop

```
    for(int i = 1 + offset; i <= pageSetPerBatch + offset && (i - 1) * resultPerPage < records; i++) {
        if(currentPage == i) {
            System.out.println(i + "(Current)");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
```

Now, I know how to use `<c:forEach>` for iterating over collections, but question is, how can I convert the loop condition to JSTL/EL syntax? This is a pagination numbers by the way.

Just fooling around, I tried

```
<c:forEach begin="1" end="100" var="val">
    <c:out value="${val}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

but this is not what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
<c:forEach begin="1" end="100" var="val" varStatus="status">
   <c:choose>
      <c:when test="${currentPage == status.index}">
         <c:out value="${status.index} (Current)"/>
      </c:when>
      <c:otherwise>
         <c:out value="${status.index}"/>
      </c:otherwise>
   </c:choose>
</c:forEach>
```

But you should not use the complex logic in the frontend. It should be done in the backend instead.

Comment: How can I set the end to get the current index of the loop?

Comment: `${status.index}` - current index in the loop.